# Role Authentication in Lithium PHP

Tags: php, lithium

I understand how to check if a user exists and log them in, but I need to check what role they play (admin or client) I know to use:

```
if (!Auth::check('default')) { return $this->redirect('/'); }
```

but how would I append that to check role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Li3 only handles authentication directly in the core. For the counterpart responsibility of authorization, you need a library like [`li3_access`](https://github.com/tmaiaroto/li3_access). See the README for a breakdown of different possible configurations.

Comment: Ah it'll take some figuring out but yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you